# If $F_1\subset F_2$ then $F_2^{°}\subset F_1^{°}$

Tags: vector-spaces

I have a problem with a simple proof in which I don't see why the argument is true.

Let $E$ be a vector space and $E^*$ be its dual and $F^°=\{ f \in E^*, \forall x\in F, f(x)=0\}$.

> The theorem i found in my [pdf](http://les.mathematiques.free.fr/pdf/dual.pdf) at the begining of the page two,
>   says that if $F_1$ and $F_2$ are two subset vector of $E$ such that
>   $F_1\subset F_2$ then $F_2^{°}\subset F_1^{°}$

**Proof:** It is trivial, if $f$ is a linear form on $E$ which is zero in $F_2$, because $F_1$ is a part of $F_2$, then it is zero in $F_1$. QED

Can someone explain me where is the logic argument in this proof? I made some drawing but it doesn't help me anymore.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Let $f\in F_2^\circ$. You must show that for all $y\in F_1$, $f(y)=0$. Since $F_1\subseteq F_2$, every $y\in F_1$ is in $F_2$. And, by hypothesis, for all $x$ in $F_2$, $f(x)=0$. So $f(y)=0$.

Comment: Well I did but i don't understand why this argument is able to end the proof.

Comment: Hence every $f\in F_2^\circ$ is in $F_1^\circ$. Hence $F_2^\circ\subseteq F_1^\circ$.

Comment: Oh ok, I see. Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument basically says : if $f\in F_2^{\circ}$, then $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in F_2$. In particular, since $F_1\subset F_2$, $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in F_1$, thus $f\in F_1^{\circ}$.

Comment: Hum ok I see now, in fact it was trivial haha.